# Relation between Resonant states and Resonance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, resonance

Resonant states and Resonance can be defined as

1. A resonant state is an eigenstate of the Schrödinger equation with the Siegert condition
   given in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1044) paper.
2. Resonance is defined as condition, which leads to the peaking of Transmission coefficient to its maxima. This definition is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonances_in_scattering_from_potentials#Nature_Of_Resonance_Curves)

I am unable to understand the relation between resonance and a resonant state. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** The situation in the wiki link you shared is not applicable to resonant states.

Trying to connect various schemes for describing resonance type phenomena can be confusing, because they occur in such a wide array of physical situations, and subtleties are often glossed over in favour of simple, concrete physical examples.

For quantum scattering problems I suggest thinking in terms of the [S-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix).

Resonant states are scattering states consisting of only outgoing waves, e.g. waves moving away from some point (more correctly away from some finite range potential) -  this is the Siegert condition. They are useful when modelling radioactive decay via tunnelling, where the finite range potential corresponds to e.g. some atomic potential barrier. These resonant states clearly require the coefficient of the incoming wave to be 0. The transmission coefficient in the wiki link you shared is therefore poorly defined for such models, because there is strictly speaking no incoming particle flux.

In terms of the S-matrix, resonances in the usual sense of the word correspond to poles. In the simplest case elements of the S-matrix are given by ratios of the scattering coefficients (something like the transmission coefficient in your wikipedia link) . If the coefficient of the incoming wave is 0, these elements diverge, i.e. they are poles of the matrix, and hence resonances.

I think this is a genuinely confusing use of nomenclature that is often glossed over. I hope the above is helpful.

Comment: alright, but when coefficient of Incoming wave is 0, Transmission coefficient must diverge to $\infty$ but how is that possible if its maximum possible value is 1

Comment: @QuantumOscillator that is what I am getting at - the maximum possible value is not 1. With the Siegert condition the amplitude of the outgoing waves increase exponentially with distance.

Comment: From the abstract of the paper you linked to: "...wave functions of resonant states diverge exponentially in space."

Comment: Strictly speaking the transmission coefficient isn't even defined, as there is no incoming wave/particle flux.

Comment: Exactly, it should not be defined. Then why does my wikipedia link says that "We see that, the Transmission co-efficient $T$ reaches its maximum value of 1. This is the resonance condition, which leads to the peaking of $T$ to its maxima, called resonance."

Comment: @QuantumOscillator because there is more than one meaning of the term 'resonance', and the one in the wikipedia link is not relevant to resonant states. The only sense in which they are 'resonances' is the one I outlined in my answer - they correspond to poles of the S-matrix.

Comment: @QuantumOscillator have my comments answered your questions? Do you need further detail?